# recursive functions c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a recursive function that has two functions, one to add numbers from 0 to 10 and then the other to retrieve the first function return value and subtract it until it reaches 0. Although, my code only adds them up 10 for the calls. Can someone shed some light. thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

static int recurse(int count)
{

   cout << count << "\n";

   if (count < 10)
   {
      recurse(count + 1);
   }

   int aRet = count;
   return count;
}

static int minusRecusive(int minus)
{

   recurse(1);
   cout << "\n\t" << minus;
   int a =0;
   minus = recurse(a);

   if (minus < 1)
   {
      recurse(minus - 1);
   }

   return minus;
}


int main()
{
   minusRecusive(1);
   cin.get();
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question about this?

Comment: Where are you adding the numbers from 0 to 10 ? Your only addition is the call with an incremented counter!

Comment: you first function `recurse` is nothing but `int recurse (int count){return count;}` , is that what you wanted?

Comment: The `minusRecursive` should probably all itself rather than the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recurse functions doesn't actually return the sum. If you call recurse(0) it will recurse into it 10x, but your return value would still be 0. Also, you're creating aRet but it's never used. Try the following...

```
if (count < 10) return count + recurse(count + 1);
return count;
```

Your minusRecursive function should be similar.